# This question should be re-opened

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

[Can people in Heaven communicate with each other?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14976/can-people-in-heaven-communicate-with-each-other)

[This meta post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening), which is good is quoted in the comments to help the user change the question.

From the answer to that post:

> Tip 2: Change "Is x true" to "What is the basis for believing that x is true?"

I would think that the question already fits that format. He is asking "what the Bible says about x", which I would say is the same as what the Biblical basis for believing x", which is very similar to "what is the basis for believing that x is true".

The user appears genuine as well. He is trying to grasp what the Bible says about life in heaven.

A comment says that it was unanswerable and it was closed as non-constructive. That is junk reasoning. It has at least three good answers and one mediocre answer that addresses the others then quotes D&C, which is fine in this case, but I say mediocre because the Bible was specifically requested.

There are currently two re-open votes. We only need three more. If you disagree with me please tell me why in an answer.

---

Got a [third](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8542201#8542201) and a fourth. Just one more is all we need.

---

Got the fifth vote. Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 2):

When four answers appear that basically answer the question "you're asking the wrong question, to me that's a sure sign of impending close votes.

Some factors that went into me casting the third close vote:

- I gave it a fair shake and it didn't amount to anything, I thought maybe someone could come up with a good answer that fit the question. But the question is asking "What does the Bible say about people in Heaven communicating with each other?" but ultimately the answer that's given 4 times over is "nothing." That to me screamed it needed to be closed.
- The user had lost any benefit of the doubt he may have been entitled to as a new user. When a user posts a couple of questions that are off the mark, they are and should be given a bit of leeway, but when it becomes obvious that they are posting in bad faith *all* of their content becomes subject to more scrutiny. This one doesn't pass muster for me.

When you ask "What does X say about Y" and the answer is nothing, and you get between 4 and 6 of those answers in various forms, that's a bad question to me. The answers aren't so much then answering the question as asked, but as implied, and in that case the question should be fixed in some way that it becomes answerable.

Comment: Really? The actual answers do not say "nothing" and no one appears to be saying "you are asking the wrong question" to me. I know I did not. Some say yes, another says nothing definitive but yes in D&C, and mine says it is talked about but what it means is debated, which I explored. I also don't see how the user lost credibility. I mean, did you even read my answer to it? I know I'm biased but I think it is a perfect answer.

Comment: And how does it make sense that we should close it because the answer is "no there is no evidence?"