# How do I reject a edit to my question which i disagree with?

Tags: discussion, support

There have been a couple of incidence where edits have been made to my posts which I do not agree with. Do I have the option of rejecting those edits?

Comment: You have the capability to roll back that edit. Underneath every revision except the newest, there is a button labeled "rollback".

Answer (score 7):

As El'endia Starman's comment states, you can roll back edits, and you should be able to edit it yourself after they've edited it.

Going beyond your original question a bit because it sounds like this might be a regular occurrence for you...

If you find that there's a user that's consistently editing your comments and it looks like vandalism (We've had a few of those) you can always flag your own question and notify a moderator that the activity is happening.

If you find someone editing your comments, and it doesn't look like intentional vandalism - it's just edits that you feel are unnecessary or diminish your post, but it looks like they're trying to be helpful, you might consider trying to get that person into a chat where you can talk it over. I wouldn't recommend that for someone who's intentionally vandalizing your posts, but those that are trying to help tend to be open to civil discussion.  After all, they're trying to help.  Odds are it's because they're nice.

***I'm not addressing your posts here directly with this next part, just making a general statement more applicable to new users.***

With that said, if your posts are consistently being edited in an attempt to keep them on-topic, and to avoid the "truthiness" issue, you might consider really examining the edits and questioning whether they are really that bad.

It's possible that your posts would simply be closed and deleted without the edits. You may not like the edits,  but they may be necessary to prevent the questions from being closed and deleted outright.  Often people post questions that are opinion-based, or Pastoral Advice that can be [salvaged with minor tweaks](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening).

Christianity.SE is not the easiest site to "get".  Just about everyone [misunderstands what the purpose and intent is](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt)  at first, and if you're constantly having your questions edited (peppered with comments and links to the myriad Meta posts that are intended to help people understand the guidelines) it may be time to stop, study the intended purpose of the site, and stop trying to turn it into something it's not.