# How does this question remain open while others do not?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Do Christian groups which think homosexuality is a sin think you can be a practicing homosexual and also a Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/17787/1100)

From [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3809/1100):

> Very few questions can be addressed at all of Christianity without further scoping because the as far as this site is concerned the term is an umbrella under which many different groups fall, some with hugely disparate beliefs. 99 times out of 100 you will need to scope your question to something smaller than that.

Hmm...

But this question asks: "Can one be a practicing homosexual and also a Christian?"

Also, isn't this dangerously close to "Is 'X' a sin?", which is expressly forbidden on this site?

Comment: That question is scoped specifically to groups that openly condemn groups and what they do if a practicing homosexual converts. That is borderline, but I think sufficiently scoped.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not even close to "Is X a sin".

- The first paragraph expressly identifies a subset of Christians based on a particular belief ("ones that believe X **is** a sin").
- The second and third paragraphs target a specific question about extant beliefs of **these groups**.

Nowhere in this question is in trying to determine whether X is a sin or not or whether people who believe one way or another are right or wrong. It's asking about the beliefs of a specifically identified sub-set.

Comment: Correct. They're asking if Christians *believe* that homosexuality is a sin.

Comment: @JimG. There is a world of difference between asking _«Is X a sin?»_ and asking _«How do people who believe X is a sin handle situation Y?»_. You're mistakenly conflating the two as if they were the same pattern but they are not. One this site can handle constructively, one it cannot.