# A slightly unsettling narrative

Tags: discussion

A Christian, born and raised in a Muslim majority country, and subjected to incessant harassment on account of his faith, prays deep within that there comes a day when he can live in a land where he can freely profess his love for the Lord.  By the Grace of the Lord such a day actually arrives.  He lands in what he believes is a country that was founded on Judeo-Christian values, and where he will not be required to justify his faith.  He makes a polite query to help the unfortunate souls who have not had the good fortune that he has been bestowed with, and what is the response?  **He is unceremoniously shut out.**

If you think that this is fiction, a figment of somebody's imagination, then you are wrong.  The Christian boy whose prayers, to get to a land where he can profess his love for the Lord without any harassment & intimidation, were answered is none other than your truly.  The evidence of enlightened souls trying to shut me up is [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91667/consolidating-christian-polemics-material-01) and [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91682/looking-for-christian-polemic-repositories) and [possibly here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91689/urls-for-christian-polemic-repositories) as well.

**With friends like these, Christians need no enemies!**

Answer (score 4):

#### Addressing a misunderstanding

**You are welcome to this site!**  In this answer I would like to address some mismatched expectations from you:

> He makes a polite query to help the unfortunate souls who have not had the good fortune that he has been bestowed with, and what is the response? **He is unceremoniously shut out.**

> The evidence of enlightened souls trying to shut me up is [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91667/consolidating-christian-polemics-material-01) and [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91682/looking-for-christian-polemic-repositories) and [possibly here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91689/urls-for-christian-polemic-repositories) as well.  **With friends like these, Christians need no enemies!**

Most participants in this community are committed Christians like yourself.  But just because your question does not fit the site, it doesn't mean we want to exclude you nor to treat you like enemies!

#### A different kind of fight

Most of us also have our share of having to defend our faith to misrepresentation, or even hostile charges by non-Christians, although in countries with religious freedom such as United States, Canada, or United Kingdom, the challenge comes more from having to **defend Christianity as the *true organized religion* as well as Christianity as the *true philosophy*** from charges that both are damaging to human flourishing, damaging to national interest, or at best irrelevant.  So in the West, we are

- fighting against **people's apathy of going to church**, and
- fighting to **compete with false solutions** to the unquenchable religious desire in human nature in the form of:

  - other organized religions (Islam, Judaism, Hinduism, Buddhism) and
  - non-institutionalized religions (atheism, agnosticism, New age movements, non-Christian spiritualities / mysticism).

Yes, we are not arrested simply by professing our faith, and churches are not in fear of being closed by government.  But if Christians want to transform society and culture through **public** institutions we STILL have to fight hard through lawsuits (such as [this recent Supreme Court case](https://www.si.com/fannation/college/cfb-hq/ncaa-football/supreme-court-decision-football-coach-prayed-on-field)) or through fighting dehumanization in culture (pornography, abortion, corruption of the Christian institution of marriage, drugs, etc.)

#### What this site is for

Although `apologetics` questions are welcome in Christianity.SE, not all questions work in this site.  C.SE is *not* a general Q&A forum like Reddit.  I encourage you to review the [Christian topics](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that this site is designed to be.  This site is mainly for Q&A on **Christian Theology** while our sister site [Hermeneutics.SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) is mainly for discussion on Biblical text interpretation.  Since your questions are mainly about answering Islam's misinterpretation of Christianity, a steep background in **Islamic theology**, **Koran exegesis/commentary** (*tafsir*), and **Islamic tradition** (*hadith*/*sunnah*) is needed but which unfortunately most participants here do not have.

Although there is a handful of questions on other religions (those tagged with `islam`, `hinduism`, or `buddhism`), we require that **these questions ask for topics in Christian theology or Biblical exegesis** instead of questions on how Christians would answer interpretations of other religion's sacred texts (unless you provide the other religion's textual interpretation on common topics such as God / Salvation / Eschatology / Spirituality, etc. in the OP for a Christian to respond from a Christian theological point of view).

#### Repositories of Christian apologetics / polemical material

In the Western world, books or websites of Christian apologetics have become very specialized, as the material is vast, requiring specialized authors or editors.  It is **unlikely** that you will find *in a single place* all materials that an apologist finds useful to talk to non-Christians.

Rather, an apologist will *first* select an angle from which to defend Christianity and *then* select a well-known expert / book / institute / coursework in the field.

- If the angle is Islam, I would refer you to websites specifically designed for Christian defense from Islam point of view, such as [Answering Islam](https://www.answering-islam.org/) suggested by @curiousdannii.
- If the angle is scientism, materialistic, or naturalistic philosophy, an example is C.S. Lewis books.
- If the angle is defending the Bible, a classic compendium is Josh McDowell's [Evidence That Demands a Verdict](https://www.christianbook.com/evidence-demands-verdict-changing-skeptical-world/josh-mcdowell/9781401676704/pd/676704) which has been updated several times.
- etc.

Because of the vastness of the material, it becomes necessary for you to restrict your inquiry to a particular topic, tagged with `resource-request`.  You can also try the [Upper Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room) chatroom.

Comment: "more from atheism / apathy to religion, rather than outright hostility from other religions"... except "atheism", or more accurately *Materialism* or *Secular Humanism* is *absolutely* a religion. And, like Islam, it is a religion that makes "persecute Christians" one of its fundamental goals. (Not "persecute other *religions*", even. They are very specifically targeting *Christians*.)

Comment: @Matthew I respect your defining "religion" more expansively than what (I argue) is more common: religion as not only a system of beliefs about God (which includes atheism), **but also need to include** explicit rituals (including liturgies) and practices (including prayers, sacraments) that worship such God to be called a "religion".  Thus people normally would associate "religion" with systems of beliefs that include worship-specific practices as in the 5 world religions.  For the same reason, some people hesitate to call Confucianism a religion as it doesn't have explicit worship to God.

Comment: "...some people hesitate to call Confucianism a religion...", yup, I'd have to disagree there. When (significantly different) religions ("philosophies", if you prefer) go to war (not necessarily with guns), it is rarely over rituals. When Humanists attack "religion", they aren't attacking the color choice of the vestments or whether the priest/pastor wears a robe, they're attacking the Christian *philosophy*. When you said "atheism / apathy to religion", *you* (and atheists) aren't using it in the sense of "rituals". (con't...)

Comment: (...con't) The reason I insist on calling Atheism / Humanism a "religion" is because that's the terminology *they* use. If Christ's enemies want to admit that their objection isn't to religion at all, but to the *philosophy* of Christianity, then I'm happy to use "religion" as you do. What I *don't* intend to do is allow them to assign different meaning to words depending on context in order to attack "religion" while claiming they aren't "religious".

Comment: @Matthew I agree that the term "religion" in public discourse has multiple meanings.  Even religious studies scholars are having difficulty to define the proper meaning of the term which appears in the very name of their discipline!  Your point about atheists assigning different meanings to "religion" is well taken.  But personally, I would clarify with my debate partner on a case by case basis, using adjective such as "organized religion" when appropriate, and confront them that as a solution to a religious question, atheism **IS** a religion.  Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Hello and welcome to our site. Please don't think that you're unwelcome here or being shut out. That is not the case. But this site can be a little confusing and many people have come here not understanding its purpose at the beginning. Unlike other sites you may be more familiar with, this one is quite strict about sticking only to questions and answers. And those questions should be ones that are, at least in theory, objectively answerable, and answerable with concise responses, typically between 200-2000 words.

I suggest you have a read of these pages:

- [The site tour](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [How we are different than other sites](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/6071)
- [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1379/6071)
- [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)
- [What makes a good focused question?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/6071)
- [Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/6071)

So for specific advice, if we consider the questions you've asked before, two simply were not questions at all, and so needed to be closed. This site can't be used like a message board or blog, 'questions' that don't actually ask anything will be removed.

Your [second question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/91682/6071) then asked for recommendations for Christian apologetics/polemics websites, of which there are so many. Recommendations don't really fit the Stack Exchange model because answers are usually quite opinion based, and they're not very objective questions either. So unfortunately that question also needed to be closed. Your [third question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/91689/6071) is very similar and might end up closed too.

Your [last question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/91702/6071) hasn't been closed yet either, but to be honest I think it probably will be. It too is not asking an objective question about Christian doctrine and practice, but instead of which verses we think would give comfort to the oppressed, and the truth is that there are hundreds and thousands of those verses.

I strongly encourage you to read the links I posted above before asking your next question, and in particular [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071) as it was written to help people in a similar situation to you, who have been having their questions closed.